# From MS Word, how can I add a slide in Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

I am trying to add a slide in a Presentation but I am having an error.

[image]

**Context**:
I have a word file that contains more than 200 pages. Each page contains an image (a screenshot). I want to create a PowerPoint document and for each images in the MS Word document; I want to paste the picture in a blank layout slides.

```
Sub transfert_image_from_WORD_to_PowerPoint()
'I added a Reference Object to this Module (PowerPoint)

'Variable creation
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application

Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
pptApp.Visible = True
Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add

'add Slides
Dim pptSlide As Slide
Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout

Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(0).CustomLayout
'Set pptSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(0, pptLayout)

'Word object creation to contains images.
Dim pic As InlineShape
Dim pslides As Slides

'loop through eanch Picutures in MS Word
For Each pic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    pic.Select
    Selection.Copy
    'Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
Next

End Sub
```

I have an error in the line `Set pptLayout`

Comment: add a slide first then attempt to access it?...

Comment: Hi @Sorceri thanks for the hint, but how do I accomplish that?

Comment: I have this error: `ActiveX can't create object Run-time-error: 429` that comes form the line `....Slides.AddSlide(0, pptLayout)`

Comment: In VBA collections are 1 based not zero based.  Therefore you can't reference slides(0) as it doesn't (can't) exist.  You will  need to add a slide(1) to a newly created presentation before you can reference it.  e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you aer using ActivePresentation when you create a Presentation object.  Anyway,  here is how you can add a slide.  You use the Add method of the CustomeLayouts collection, then you can add a slide

```
Set pptLayout = pptPres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts.Add(1)
Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.AddSlide(1, pptLayout)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sorceri, I was stuck by having the wrong syntax  `Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout `